# Run time penalty in Variable Length arrays?

Tags: c++

Reference to the Stackoverflow question title ["variable length arrays in C++"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c?rq=1) we know that following is valid

```
void foo(int n) {
    int values[n]; //Declare a variable length array
}
```

I have read that there exists a small run time penalty(in variable length arrays) here. Can somebody nicely explain what that is in this context?

I would also try my level best to locate the link where I read it.I apologize i could not mention it here.

Comment: It would be nice if you actually had a *link* to the question you reference. Also, variable-length arrays didn't technically exist in C++ until the C++14 standard, though many compilers had it as an extension.

Comment: Most things have a cost associated with them. VLAs are no exception. When you say there's a penalty, you mean as compared to what?

Comment: As compared to normal way of when we use arrays like int values[10];

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Apparently VLA's didn't make it into C++14 after all: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C%2B%2B14&diff=591269892&oldid=589637208

Comment: Follow standard, use `vector<int>` instead.

Comment: @janneb Oh, missed that! Doesn't seem to be included (yet) for C++17 either. Anyway, using `std::vector` should give all benefits of VLAs without the drawbacks (though it adds other drawbacks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, with GCC, functions with VLA's:

- Will not be inlined
- Need to use an extra register for the frame pointer (that is, `-fomit-frame-pointer` works on non-VLA functions), so there is one less register available for the other work the function needs to do.

Comment: Also, if the VLA is placed before other variables in the stack frame, one can no longer use constant offsets to access them.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev: Good point. Though I think by using either the stack or frame pointer, constant offsets can be used (hence why -fomit-frame-pointer is disabled for VLA functions). But if there are variables placed between two VLA's then I see no other way than to compute the offset at runtime.

Comment: Even if VLAs are put "last", there's the case of multiple VLAs... then the address of all-but-the-first will depend on the cummulative size of the earlier ones.  And you can't actually put the non-VLA ones first without taking a worst-case high watermark of all memory needed for variables in internal `{}` scopes (e.g. `for`, `while`) in a function, so the performance impact's unlikely to be restricted to VLA access.